# Handling status bar notification before it is displayed

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using `NotificationListenerService` to handle device notifications:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    Log.d(TAG,"onNotificationPosted posted - ID :" + sbn.getId() + "\t"
            + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\t" + sbn.getPackageName());
 }
```

The `onNotificationPosted()` method is called after the notification has been posted on the device. Is there a way to catch it before it is presented?

I saw that reading notifications can also be achieved using the  [AccessibilityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager.html) but again it's read after the notification popped.

Is there a way to delay the device notifications pop-ups until some moment?

I know I can delete a notification using the `NotificationListenerService` as it come (after it popped to the user) and save it and try to relaunch it later. But I am having issues with the relaunching and again this is happening after the status bar notification is already shown.

Comment: what kind of notifications you are talking about? gcm push Notifications? or any other...why can't you do all the necessary work before showing it?

Comment: All apps on the device notifications. i will be happy to do the work before showing it how do i cathc those notifications?

Comment: AFAIK android's Notification Listener is the only way to handle Notifications but after showing it. Otherwise there is no other way or at-least any I know of.

Comment: Is your goal to hide (or otherwise control) when notifications arrive and not display them and distract the user?

If so, is Hiding the Status Bar a possible (or partial) solution ?

Comment: You could prompt the user to prioritize and toggle notifications with ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS. Start an activity with this in the intent to bring up the Notifications screen.

Comment: have you found any solution

Answer (score 7):

At present, using `NotificationListenerService` is the only way to be notified of and interact with `StatusBarNotifications`. Intercepting and handling the notifications before they even reach the status bar is not allowed, and would represent a rather notable security violation - this is also confirmed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286087/intercepting-notifications.

If this were possible then an application could in theory block all notifications for all other applications system wide, which would not be a good thing. Furthermore, even with `NotificationListenerService` you may only see notifications from other applications, not alter or delete them. Methods to modify/cancel application notifications, namely `cancelAllNotifications()`, only serve to alter the notifications generated by the calling application.